# Django redirecting to detail page after creating post (FBV)

Tags: python, django

I am making simple blog right now.

I am trying to redirect page after creating post.

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models

from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.conf import settings
from django.dispatch import receiver


class FreeBoardPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


@receiver(post_delete, sender=FreeBoardPost)
def freeboard_image_delete(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.image.delete(False)
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import FreeBoardListView, FreeBoardDetailView, create_freeboard_view

urlpatterns = [
    path("", FreeBoardListView.as_view(), name="freeboard"),
    path("<int:pk>/", FreeBoardDetailView.as_view(), name="freeboard_detail"),
    path("create/", create_freeboard_view, name="freeboard_create"),
]
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from .models import FreeBoardPost
from .forms import CreateFreeBoardPost
from users.models import CustomUser


class FreeBoardListView(ListView):
    model = FreeBoardPost
    template_name = "bbs/freeboard/free_board.html"
    context_object_name = "free_board_list"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return FreeBoardPost.objects.order_by("-id")


class FreeBoardDetailView(DetailView):
    model = FreeBoardPost
    template_name = "bbs/freeboard/free_board_detail.html"


def create_freeboard_view(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(FreeBoardPost, pk=pk)
    context = {}

    user = request.user
    if not user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("login")

    form = CreateFreeBoardPost(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        author = CustomUser.object.filter(email=user.email).first()
        obj.author = author
        obj.save()
        return redirect("freeboard_detail", pk=post.pk)

    context["form"] = form

    return render(request, "bbs/freeboard/free_board_create.html", context)
```

The `views.py` code gave me an error `create_freeboard_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'`.

Is there way I can redirect at FBV?

If not, I want to change this code to CBV. But I don't know how.

I searched for this and tried in different ways, but It still doesn't work.

I want to get an id of a post and redirect to that link.

Answer (score 0):

Your `create_freeboard_view` view has a required argument `pk` however the url that's pointing to it is missing this argument.  You could update the url to something like...

`path("create/<int:pk>/", create_freeboard_view, name="freeboard_create"),`

...to capture this `pk` argument in the url.

Further info in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#path

Comment: Oh got it. Thank you so much :D